# Calculating relative effect size with standard mean difference and 95%CI

Tags: effect-size

I have effect size (standard mean difference) and 95%CI for a meta-analysis. How can I calculate the relative effect size using this information? Other information I have includes pooled SD for intervention group and control group pre- and post-, n. Appreciate for any advice that does NOT require coding software.

Comment: Also, how to obtain the 95% CI from the relative effect size?

Comment: What is a relative effect size?

Comment: @COOLSerdash , maybe take a look at this website - it explains relative vs absolute effect size quite succinctly.  https://www.cebm.ox.ac.uk/resources/top-tips/explaining-absolute-and-relative-effect-sizes-in-a-way-youll-never-forget.